# jQueryセレクタで、Selector (“selector1", "selector2”)はどういう意味でしょうか？

Tags: jquery

**jQueryドキュメントに、下記セレクタは掲載されているのですが、**

> Selector (“selector1, selector2”)

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

---

**下記セレクタが見当たりません。**
・どういう解釈の挙動になるのでしょうか？
・掲載されていないということは使わない方が良いのでしょうか？

> Selector (“selector1", "selector2”)

Comment: どこで見られたんでしょうか？ 通常２番目の引数はコンテキスト（検索場所を表す）だと思いますが・

Comment: (公式サイト以外の)どこかのページで以前見た気がするのですが、どこで見たのか思い出せません

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**短い回答**

> ・どういう解釈の挙動になるのでしょうか？

`$("selector2").find("selector1")`として動作します。
selector2のDOMを起点としてselector1のDOMを探します。

> ・掲載されていないということは使わない方が良いのでしょうか？

jQueryの第二引数に関するドキュメントは下記のページにあります。
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

**長い回答**

Selectorの第二引数`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`は下記です。

Selector Context
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ).

通常はdocument rootからDOMの検索をしますが、`context`が指定された場合はそのElement(or jQuery)からDOMの検索を行います。

`$( "span", this )`は`$( this ).find( "span" )`と等価になります。

> context
>   Type: Element or jQuery
>   A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

正確には、第二引数に指定するのはSelectorではなく、Element or jQueryです。
Selectorを指定した場合、`this.context`は`document`になります。

ですが、`.context`は既に非推奨のプロパティであり、jQuery 3.xで削除されるため、Selectorを指定しても問題はないかと思われます。
(`$("context").find("selector")`として動作します)

Category: Deprecated 1.10
http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.10/

Breaking change: Deprecated `.context` and `.selector` properties removed
https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-deprecated-context-and-selector-properties-removed

---

```js
var noContext = $("li", "ul.list");
var context   = $("li", $("ul.list")[0]);

console.log(noContext.context); // = document
console.log(context.context);   // = ul.list
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

---

余談ですが、第一引数のSelectorにidセレクターのみ指定した場合、第二引数は無視され`document.getElementById()`が使用されます。
(id要素はHTML内でユニーク(一意)であるため)